# How do I get the object to correctly display?

Tags: python

I am trying to display some information about an object, including the name, but instead, it is displaying a weird string. I am pretty new to python, and I have just started working with classes.

This is the code I wrote:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(name,item):
        name.item = item
    def display(name):
        print(f"Name: {name}\nItem: {name.item}")
testname = Test("test")
testname.display()
```

And I got:

```
Name: <__main__.Test object at 0x7f76f0733f10>
Item: test
```

instead of:

```
Name: testname
Item: test
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr)

Comment: Why didn't you name the first argument `self` as is the convention? You are making everything much more confusing for yourself. `name` is not a name, but a instance of `Test`

Comment: Where do you think your code would come up with the `str` value `'testcode`? You don't supply it anywhere, and nothing in your class constructs the name from anything.

Comment: @chepner the string 'testcode' was not what I meant to put there, I meant to say 'testname'

Comment: `testname` is not the name of the object; it's the name of *one* variable that refers to the object. The object itself knows nothing about it.

Comment: Imagine `a = b = Test("test")`. What name do think the object would have?

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening here is you are printing the object itself, or the instance of the class. The 0x7f76f0733f10 is the memory address where that object lives if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that, it would be better if you used "self" because it is a convention. You need to use the `__str__` method in order to give your class a proper name.

```
def __str__(name):
    return "testcode"
```